# Bar chart does't show till I resize the browser window using CanvasJS, HTML and Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, canvasjs

I have made a bar chart using using CanvasJS,HTML and angular, the issue I am facing is that the ***bar chart shows only when I resize the browser***,how do I resolve this issue.

**The TypeScript code is:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as CanvasJS from 'node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.min'

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-c2',
  templateUrl: './c2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c2.component.css']
})
export class C2Component implements OnInit {

constructor(){


}

  ngOnInit() {
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
      text: "Basic Column Chart in Angular"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { y: 71, label: "Apple" },
        { y: 55, label: "Mango" },
        { y: 50, label: "Orange" },
        { y: 65, label: "Banana" },
        { y: 95, label: "Pineapple" },
        { y: 68, label: "Pears" },
        { y: 28, label: "Grapes" },
        { y: 34, label: "Lychee" },
        { y: 14, label: "Jackfruit" },
        { y: 14, label: "Guava" }
      ]
    }]
  });

  chart.render();

    }
    }
```

**The HTML code is:**

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 55%; width: 55%;" ></div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz of your issue ?

Comment: @vasu-sharma,
Seems to be working. Take a look at this [Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-angular-column-chart). If you are still facing issue, create a Stackblitz and share it so that others can run the code to understand your scenario and help you resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CanvasJS angular chart component to create [column chart](https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/angular-column-charts/) in angular way. Below is the working code with your chart options.

```
/* app.component. ts */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  chart: any;
    
  chartOptions = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
      text: "Basic Column Chart in Angular"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { y: 71, label: "Apple" },
        { y: 55, label: "Mango" },
        { y: 50, label: "Orange" },
        { y: 65, label: "Banana" },
        { y: 95, label: "Pineapple" },
        { y: 68, label: "Pears" },
        { y: 28, label: "Grapes" },
        { y: 34, label: "Lychee" },
        { y: 14, label: "Jackfruit" },
        { y: 14, label: "Guava" }
      ]
    }]
  } 
}

/* app.component. ts */
<div>
    <canvasjs-chart [options]="chartOptions" [styles]="{width: '100%', height:'360px'}"></canvasjs-chart>    
</div>
```